# Can I run my dell e1505 with my x1400 graphic card removed?

Tags: laptop

I'm trying to troubleshoot my laptop turning black randomly (and the sound cutting off afterwards but the power is still on). The graphic card is removable.

Comment: Its very unlikely that your GPU is removable.  Most mobile GPU solutions are soldered onto the motherboard.

Comment: Well I'm looking at it and it has a pci-e connector.

Comment: What exactly has the pci-e connector?  If you are talking about the laptop itself, thats a different type of pci-e connector, you can't connect a graphics card to it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the processor, and if it has an integrated GPU. It's likely your model has a Core 2 Duo, something like [T7200](http://cpuboss.com/cpu/Intel-Core2-Duo-T7200), which does not have an internal GPU and therefore will not work without a graphics card. But best check which Processor is used inside your laptop (under "system"), and look up if it has a GPU or not.

Comment: I have a t2300. On further research, it seems the motherboard doesn't have a secondary gpu to fallback to.